# Сохранить из csv-файла только данные с определенным атрибутом

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно из огромного csv-файла выбрать и сохранить новый файл только с теми теми id, которые имеют в столбце `Language` атрибут `ru`?

Например если файл выглядит вот так:

```
ID,Language,Geolocation_cordinate,RT
136612,en,NO,NO
125513,ru,NO,NO
143323,ru,NO,No
164483,fr,NO,No
```

То вывод должен быть таким:

```
ID,Language,Geolocation_coordinate,RT
125513,ru,NO,NO
143323,ru,NO,NO
```

Comment: у вас в реальных данных тоже есть пустые строки в файле и повторяющаяся строка "1. Элемент списка" ? Если это так, то у вас "невалидный" (сломанный) CSV файл

Comment: нет, в вопросе я хотела показать, что каждый id это новая строка

Comment: а пробелы после разделителя (запятой) у вас есть в реальных данных - или это опять для красоты сделано?  PS лучше приводить пример данных в вопросе максимально приближенный к реальным данным

Comment: Тоже без пробела. Я действительно хотела здесь "покрасивее" оформить его. Полный файл выглядит вот так: Tweet_ID,Language,Geolocation_coordinate,RT,Likes,Retweets,Country,Date Created
1370893837946658818,en,NO,YES,0,2,"",Sun Mar 14 00:25:35 +0000 2021
1370895128693473280,en,NO,YES,0,51,"",Sun Mar 14 00:30:43 +0000 2021

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

filename = r"/path/to/input/filename.csv"

(pd
 .read_csv(filename, skipinitialspace=True)
 .query("Language == 'ru'")
 .to_csv(r"result.csv", index=False))
```

Comment: Я хотела бы еще у вас спросить. Если у меня большое количество этих csv-файлов, которые расположены на компьютере по месяцам и имеют следующую структуру: tweets --> tweets_maerz (.csv, .csv, .csv ...), tweets_april (.csv, .csv, .csv) то как можно использовать написанную вами программу чтобы в один файл собрать все русские твиты из всех csv-файлов и сохранить их в одном файле?

Comment: @Kathi, думаю можно. Лучше открыть новый вопрос и привести в нем маленькие примеры данных для двух файлов (по 3-5 строк для каждого) и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Да, я сейчас сделаю. Спасибо вам большое за помощь!